# android - getting the selected item from listview

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I am trying to get an item from a listview and pass it to a new activity in a textview, where i would eventually make some modifications.

> MainActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

    makeListView();
    getClick();
}
private void makeListView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.items, input);
    ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    lista.setAdapter(adapter);

}

private void getClick() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    lista.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View viewClicked, int pos, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("test", input[pos].toString());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

> SecondActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String myString = extras.getString("test");

    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    text.setText(myString);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();

    }
}
```

I am getting an error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.shoplist/com.example.shoplist.Second
>        * Activity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f080000 for fragment PlaceholderFragment

What can i do?

Comment: You can start by posting the entire stacktrace

Comment: and the code from `PlaceholderFragment()` as well as this problem is caused by confusion in fragments and activities

Comment: Please post the content of the layout file R.layout.second_activity

Comment: Please post the stacktrace and the PlaceHolderFragment code

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with your MainActivity. It has nothing to do with a listview and not with passing the right info by an intent. The problem lies with instantiating a fragment in your second activity.

Comment: here you can find my log: http://www.speedyshare.com/MEPe9/log.txt

Comment: I managed to find out what was the problem. I did not declared the activity in the Android Manifest file. It`s working fine now. Thank you all for the help! :)